# I can not show HTML in the Google Charts tooltip

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have a problem when I want to place HTML code in the tooltip that is displayed when hovering over an element of the histogram.

Did someone have a similar problem?
I leave my [code](https://jsfiddle.net/gr41x9tj/13/)

```
function drawChart() {
//var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataToHistogram(response));
var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
dataTable.addColumn({'type': 'string', 'role': 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}});
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'number', id: 'precio' });


for (var i = datos.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  dataTable.addRow(["<strike>"+datos[i].titulo+"</strike>", datos[i].valor]);
}


var options = {
  title: '',
  legend: { position: 'none' },
  bar: {groupWidth : 20},
  width: 1200,
  series: [
    {color: '#007d00', visibleInLegend: true}, {}, {},
  ],
  isStacked: 'absolute',
  tooltip:{isHtml: true}
};

var chart = new google.visualization.Histogram(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(dataTable, options);
```

}

I based on this

[https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content#using-html-tooltips][2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Supported Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content#supported-charts) section of the documentation, in indicates that Histograms do not support HTML tooltips.  Here's the quote:

> Supported charts
>
> HTML tooltips are currently supported for the
> following chart types:
>
> - AreaChart
> - BarChart
> - CalendarChart
> - CandlestickChart
> - ColumnChart
> - ComboChart
> - LineChart
> - PieChart
> - Sankey Diagrams
> - ScatterChart
> - Timeline